# Azure AD Login in multiple sites with same Toke

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

The layout of my situation is as follows.

I have two applications, one will authenticate by Azure Ad, and depending on the logged in user will be shown a link to the second application.
In localhost, it works without problems, the second application can read the token used in the first application and authenticates the user.

But when I publish in my DEV environment, the second application can not read the cookie, and to authenticate the user the Azure page is shown again.

It seems that in localhost the cookie is accessed without any problems, but when I publish from IIS on a valid domain this does not happen.

My code:

```
 
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    //app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        CookieName = "NameOfMyApp",
        CookieDomain = "mydomain.com"
    });
    app.Use(async (context, next) => { await next.Invoke(); });

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(this.CreateB2EOptions());
    app.Use(async (context, next) => { await next.Invoke(); });

}

private OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions CreateB2EOptions()
{
    return new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Authority = string.Format(b2e.AadInstance, "common"),
        ClientId = b2e.ClientId,
        RedirectUri = sso.RedirectUri,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = sso.RedirectUri,
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications { AuthenticationFailed = this.AuthenticationFailed },
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { ValidateIssuer = false, SaveSigninToken = true  },
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
        AuthenticationType = "OpenIdConnect-B2E"
    };

}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by "the second application can read the token used in the first application and authenticates the user." ? How do you achieve that in second application , with openid connect or with your own code ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
Both applications will share the Cookie with the claims.
To do this, both applications need to share the same machinekey in web.config.

web.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <machineKey decryptionKey="DECRYPTIONKEY" validationKey="VALIDATION_KEY" /> 
    </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

ConfigureAuth

```
 
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        CookieName = "NameOfMyApp",
        CookieDomain = "mydomain.com",
        CookiePath = "/"
    });    
}
```

This way both will share the same cookie, if the first application logs out, the second one will also need to log in again.